# Show that all perfect squares are of the form $4k$ or $4k+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please also tell me how to figure out what to do and how to do such question? 
Thank you :)

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951518/proving-that-for-all-n%e2%88%88-mathbb-n-if-n2-4qr-for-q-r-%e2%88%88-mathbb-z-with-0%e2%89%a4) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99716/the-square-of-an-integer-is-congruent-to-0-or-1-mod-4).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with the fact that any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is odd or even. Thus may be expressed as $2k$ or $2k+1$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now, what happens when you square those expressions?

Answer (score 1):

Use *congruences modulo* $4$:

Any integer is congruent to $0, 1,2$ or $3\mod4$, so any square is congruent to $0^2=0$, $1^2=1$, $2^2\equiv 0$ or $3^2\equiv 1\mod4$. To sum it up, any square is congruent to $0$ or $1\mod4$.

Comment: This is a bit like swatting a fly with a sledgehammer. You don't need congruence classes for this, and given that the OP asks such a question I doubt he is familiar with the concept.

Comment: Well, in my opinion, anyone from beginning of high school should be aware of congruences, because it's such a *simplification*. Just like college students should know about  equivalence of functions, instead of invoking over and over  ‘L'Hospital, L'Hospital, …’

Comment: Sure, students should know a lot more, but students should also easily be able to prove that any square is congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$. The fact that the OP does not know suggests he does not fall in the category of students you are referring to.

Comment: Well TMM you figured it right, I'm indeed unfamiliar with this concept. Well,  I want to study the basics of this in much more detail,  can anyone help me out.  I mean where and what to start?

Comment: You can look at [Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) Wikipedia notice. It is only a way to remove irrelevant details from arithmetic calculations.